# Can we catch scenario's error logs from command prompt through hooks of cucumberjs

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using protractor-cucumber framework.I am able to catch the scenario status by below code

```
After(function (scenario) {
 console.log(scenario.result.status);
});
```

so like wise can i get errors of that scenario(if any) as

```
scenario.result.description
```

but scenario.result.description is not working.So how can i catch the errors in cucumber-protractor framework.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try below code,its working for me

```
After(function (scenario) {
   if(scenario.result.exception!=null){
     console.log("Exception is.........."+scenario. result.exception);
    }
});
```